# Rspec : Custom Matchers : want a matcher with behavior just opposite of existing matcher

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, cancan

I have a situation

```
let(:user) { create(:user, organization: org, role_ids: [Role::ROLE_CSA]) }
subject(:ability) { Ability.new(user) }
describe 'Not Permitted' do

  # I need this
  it { is_expected_not_to (be_able_to(:index, AdminsController)) }

  # Or this
  it { is_expected_to (not_be_able_to(:index, AdminsController)) }
end
```

**But** unfortunately I found that the `is_expected_not_to` and `not_be_able_to` are not available.

I could do in this way

```
  it 'should not permit' do
    expect(ability).not_to be_able_to(:index, AdminsController)
  end
```

But If possible I would like to use the `short form` instead. Is there any way I can achieve what I want?

If not, I would like to create new `custom matcher` which has behavior just opposite to `be_able_to` of `CanCan` or `is_expected_to` if possible. can anybody help?

Comment: Can you just add a bang `!` in front of the `is`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from: https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/subject/one-liner-syntax

You should be able to do:

```
it { is_expected.not_to (be_able_to(:index, AdminsController)) }
```